# How to set a Dependency Property Value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

*Please reference code below for context.*

- On start up, the Text of the 2 TextBoxes will be "This is the Original Value".
- When the `TestBox`'s button ("Test Button") is clicked:

  - the text of the `TestBox`'s `TextBox` will change to "Set By Test Button"
  - the other TextBox's value will NOT change.
- When the `Window`'s button is clicked, the text of BOTH TextBoxes *should* change to "Set By Window". *However, only the plain TextBox gets updated, the `TestBox` does not.* **<-- THIS IS THE BUG!**

It seems that the way i'm (re)setting the `Test` property from within the `TestBox` obliterates the binding.

**What is the proper way of changing a Dependency Property from within the user control itself without breaking bindings?**

---

### Example code:

I've got a UserControl, `TestBox` that looks like this:

**TestBox.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Company.UserControls.TestBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="TextBoxControl">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox MinWidth="100" Name="TestTextBox" 
            Text="{Binding Path=Test, ElementName=TextBoxControl, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         />
        <Button MinWidth="100" Content="Test Button" 
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**TestBox.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Company.UserControls
{
    public partial class TestBox
    {
        public const string TestString = "Set By Test Button";

        public TestBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = 
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "Test", 
                    typeof(string), typeof(TestBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
        public string Test
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
        }
        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /****** THIS OBLITERATES THE BINDING ******/
        Test = TestString;
            /****** THIS OBLITERATES THE BINDING ******/
        }
    }
}
```

And a Window that uses the control like this:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="Company.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:u="clr-namespace:Company.UserControls"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyTestValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <u:TestBox x:Name="MyTestBox" 
                   Test="{Binding Path=MyTestValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Click" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Company
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyStackPanel.DataContext = new MyThing
            {
                MyTestValue = "This is the Original Value"
            };
        }
        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyStackPanel.DataContext = new MyThing
            {
                MyTestValue = "Set by Window"
            };
        }
    }

    public class MyThing
    {
        public string MyTestValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're binding `OneWay`, the binding `Source` will not be updated when the `Target` changes, hence other `Target`s bound against the same `Source` won't be modified either... Seems pretty obvious.. see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand how Binding Sources and Targets work.

Comment: Bindings within the windows are oneway, set them to two way and everything updates.  Also, you're binding to a POCO property, so you're not getting update notifications... I'm not sure what your desired behavior is, so I can't tell what's actually wrong...

Comment: Also, changing a UI element's `DataContext` will not affect others (unless they're logical child of the UI element in question and they don't have an explicitly defined `DataContext` themselves...

Comment: @HighCore, right, and that is *exactly* what I want.

Comment: @Will, @HighCore, "When the `Window`'s button is clicked, the text of BOTH TextBoxes should change to "Set By Window". **However, only the plain `TextBox` gets updated, *the `TestBox` does not*.**"

Comment: @Will, also, in this example, I don't care about update notifications on the `Window` bindings, as I'm only testing changing the entire `DataContext` itself, not any of its properties - hence the `OneWay` bindings on the `Window`. In my real code I do implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, though.

Comment: With all that said, please let me know if I can clarify anything else about the question. `</comment-storm>`

Comment: "However, only the plain TextBox gets updated, the TestBox does not." because **oneway**.  Is there a reason why you have to have the binding be one way only?

Comment: @Will, Yes, the user will need to confirm a set of changes. At which time I write all of the updated values back to the original DataContext.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Probably not. I may have just hacked it in another way without the binding. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are asking the binding system to get out of sync. The whole system is designed to keep all bound elements in sync. The only cases under which you can set a value on a dependency property without destroying the underlying binding are when the binding mode is set to "TwoWay" or "OneWayToSource". Under these conditions the value is transferred back to the source and consequently, the system is kept in sync. However, in your case a two way binding will cause both buttons to change both textboxes.

You will need to use two dependency properties TestBox. The first dependency property will be bound to the internal text box, and the second will be bound to in the parent window. Then you will need to add a property change handler to the second dependency property (which is done in the FrameworkPropertyMetadata). In this handler, simply set the value on the first dependency property.

Since you are using a UserControl with a code behind anyways, a simpler solution is to only have the second dependency property mentioned above and to directly set the value (from you event handler and the property change handler) onto the textbox via its x:Name.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.